# Different but similar variant of Train fly problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

(Yes, I know this question has been asked many times, this is quite similar, but not duplicate - well, you decide. If it is, I'll close it.)

**Given:** Two people **stand back to back** and at a certain moment start running in **opposite directions**, the first at 12 km/h and the second at 8 km/h.

**At the same moment** a fly starts to move between them at 20 km/h from one to the other, so that when it meets one of them he immediately reverses direction and moves to the other.

**Question:** Where will the fly be after 1 hour?

If I reverse this problem to the classic one(lets assume these are trains), and assume they 20km apart (which is where they will be in 1 hour - because we sum the speed and thus the distance is 20km), and then compute the first time it hits the second train it should be $$\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{total velocity}} * {v_{\text{fly}}} = \frac{20}{40} * 20 = 10$$

Then we continue like that but now the distance is $10$, and so on..

We will understand that the series is $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{2^n}$.

In order to understand where the fly will be after an hour (it should totally fly 20km) which can be interpreted as multiplying it by the number of time it zigzags, which converges to 20km. So $20* \sum_1^n \frac{1}{2^n} = 20$ Should be the solution.

In other words, it will finish where it originally started. Would love to know if this approach is correct or I'm mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't say where the fly will be at the end of the hour.  Your reversal approach is a good way to see it.  When they start apart and approach each other, the fly ends at the same point regardless of the starting point.  That shows in the case they are separating there is an acceptable trajectory starting at the meeting point and ending anywhere in the segment.

The problem comes because the fly is faster than each person, so it is not well defined what happens at the moment they start to separate.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I got your answer, why won't the fly be in position of the person it started from? Why it's not well defined what happens at the moment they start to seperate (I stated this is moves from person X to person Y, and vice-versa)

Comment: In the approaching version, the fly can start on either person or at any point in between and arrive at the meeting point.  In the receding version, the fly doesn't know what to do at the moment you start because the two people are touching and it is faster than either.  It has to choose between the reverses of all those approaching trajectories and has no way to do so.

Comment: @RossMillikan I'm not sure that what the riddle meant to show, after all we can think of it of series with growing sequence each second the length grows , since at a certain point the fly will reach 20km we probably can calculate it.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why not defined what happens when they start to separate? It starts from X, although its faster than both of them in the beginning it just will zigzag 'alot' between the two people in the beginning. But the accumulated distance should be 20km, and thus end up in the starting position. I'd like to wait for more answers from other people, maybe then can shed some new light on this question.

Comment: The reversal argument is enough to show that the startup is not well defined.  You are trying to "count in from infinity" and you can't do that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see Ross, that makes more sense now. Thank you very much.